# Reducing the space between two <tr> tags

Tags: html, css

I want to display a company logo and a company name right next to it. This code will run in old browsers that do not support flexbox so I need to do this in simple HTML and CSS. This is what I tried to write:

```html
 <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" width="130">
                <img src="Images/facebook.png" height="80" width="80" class="logo" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="name1">This is some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="name2">This is some text1</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

This is how the screen shot looks like:

[image: output]

Is there any way I can reduce the space between "This is some text" and "This is some text1"? I don't want to use flexbox because I am using this code on older devices. I am not very good with CSS. I can use float if anyone can help me with using float. Below are the styles that I am using:

```
 .logo {
            transform: translateX(2em);
        }
       

        .name1 {
            font-size: 25px;
            color: #e9c46a;
           
        }

        .name2 {
            font-size: 25px;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>

    .logo {
                transform: translateX(2em);
            }
           
    
            .name1 {
                font-size: 25px;
                color: #e9c46a;
               
            }
    
            .name2 {
                font-size: 25px;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Hello @Lars,

I tried first two HTMl that you posted. Somehow, the outlook browser is translating them like this:

[image]

Is there any way, I can remove those black lines in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to bring your text content closer togheter.
You probably want to apply a combination of `border-collapse` and `vertical-align` rules.

I've applied a white border to the table cells so that it becomes apparent how the rule effects your output.

The `border-collapse` will remove spacing between the cells.
The `vertical-align`  will attach the text to the bottom/top of the cell.

The image itself will cause the text cell to take up more space.
If different vertical aligns are not feasible,  you might want to decrease the image size.

The text inside the cell uses `line-height` to determine how much vertical space to take up, reducing that either via percentage or via `px` value will bring the lines even closer togheter.

```css
.logo {
  transform: translateX(2em);
}

.name1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #e9c46a;
}

.name2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  background: #ccc;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.container img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.small-image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
}

.collapse-border table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.font-aligned .name1 {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.font-aligned .name2 {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.line-height td {
  line-height: 80%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container ">
  <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" width="130">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" height="80" width="80" class="logo" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name1">original: This is some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name2">original: This is some text1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container small-image">
  <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" width="130">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" class="logo" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name1">smaller image: This is some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name2">smaller image: This is some text1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container collapse-border">
  <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" width="130">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" class="logo" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name1">collapsed border: This is some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name2">collapsed border: This is some text1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container font-aligned">
  <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" width="130">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" class="logo" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name1">font align bottom: This is some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name2">font align top: This is some text1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container line-height">
  <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" width="130">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" class="logo" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name1">line height smaller: This is some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name2">line-height smaller: This is some text1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container collapse-border font-aligned line-height">
  <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" width="130">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" height="80" width="80" class="logo" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name1">every rule: This is some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name2">every rule: This is some text1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Lars I modified my question. Somehow, I am seeing black lines in the background when I see your image. I am looking these images in MS outlook  which is really outdated

Answer (score 0):

Vertically aligning the texts to bring them closer with `valign` attribute and also removing the padding of the table cells removes more space. I hope that's close enough.

Edit: I restructured your contents within the table in a way that it will work better in email clients like Outlook.

```css
.logo {
transform: translateX(2em);
}

.name1 {
font-size: 25px;
color: #e9c46a;
}

.name2 {
font-size: 25px;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<table style="background-color: cadetblue; width:100%; padding:10px">
  <tr>
      <td width="130">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" height="80" width="80" class="logo" />
      </td>

      <td style="padding: 0;">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                  <td class="name1" valign="bottom" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: bottom;">This is some text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="name2" valign="top" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top;">This is some text1</td>
              </tr>                    
          </table>
      </td>            
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: "Note: Don't use the obsolete valign attribute. Instead, add the CSS vertical-align property to the row." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

Comment: @Alex I restructured your contents within the table in a way that it will work better in email clients like Outlook. You can give it a go.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks a lot for pointing it out. But I can see `valign` still has good browser support both for web and email. So specially for emails, I think it will be better to include both `valign` and `vertical-align` CSS property.